# Selenium-side-runner run specific chrome profile from cmd

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a specific chrome profile but presumably due to how quotes should work it gets tripped up.  Tried commands include:

`selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--profile-directory=Profile 8] browserName='chrome' "  my.side`

`selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=["--user-data-dir="C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 8""] browserName='chrome' "  my.side`

`selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=["--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 8"] browserName='chrome' "  my.side`

`selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=['--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 8'] browserName='chrome' "  my.side`

`selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--user-data-dir="C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 8"] browserName='chrome' "  my.side`

and various other combos of quotes and backquotes...

Error is one of:

1. `TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?`
2. `WebDriverError: unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 8" is still attached to a running Chrome or Chromium process`
3. Opens a new chrome Profile

All suggesting that I'm not passing this argument properly....

Answer (score 1):

I figured out something that works for me as this appears to be a bug in the documentation. This works well. The trick is to remove any '-' before 'user-data-dir' like below. This is plaguing many users. I'll look around for other places asking this same question and share.

```
selenium-side-runner  -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[user-data-dir=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\selenium] browserName=chrome" .\Test.side
```

Here's a GitHub on this issue, not solved as of this time
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/1319